# Convert geohash into lat lon values

Tags: geolocation, location, coordinates, geohashing

I have a 'location' column, containing strings like `0101000020E610000000000080FA8C384000000000526E4D40`

Is it geohash?  How to convert it in two values as latitude and longitude in R or Python or anything else?

Comment: that's not a geohash

Comment: Yes, I found out that this is Geometry from PostGis